# Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle. Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Tags: react-native

```
react-native-cli: 1.0.0
react-native: 0.39.2
```

I cloned a react native project.  Then I ran `npm install` and then `react-native run-ios`. The project fails with the below error.

> Please not the project runs fine in xcode.

Any thoughts?

The following commands produced analyzer issues:

```
Analyze RCTLocationObserver.m
```

(1 command with analyzer issues)

> The following build commands failed:
>       CompileC /Users/jordanmc/Documents/src/Safetypin%20React-Native/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTLinking.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTLinking.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTLinkingManager.o RCTLinkingManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       CompileC /Users/jordanmc/Documents/src/Safetypin%20React-Native/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTLocationObserver.o RCTLocationObserver.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       CompileC /Users/jordanmc/Documents/src/Safetypin%20React-Native/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTText.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTText.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTTextManager.o RCTTextManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   (3 failures)
>
> Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Safetypin.app
>   An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
>   Failed to install the requested application
>   An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
>   Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
>
> Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Safetypin.app/Info.plist
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I had the same problem Jordan. `react-native run-ios` creates the Products & Intermediates folder in the ./ios/build folder, but the issue is the valid path is pointing to ./ios/build/Build. What I've been doing is I manually create the Build/ folder inside ./ios/build by issuing the command below:

```
cd ./ios/build
mkdir Build
cd Build
```

then, I symlink the folders:

```
ln -s ../Products .
ln -s ../Intermediates .
```

You should be able to get `react-native run-ios` to work again.

Comment: This is an unfortunate but necessary "hack". I solved it by making custom workspace settings in XCode. In XCode 9 go to File -> Workspace Settings -> click Advanced -> select Relative to Workspace and prepend each path there with build/Build/...

Comment: On my project, `build` directory already exists in iOS/build, what can I do for this?