# Not able to install react app in iOS simulator

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am using react-native version-0.57.3

so the project was working fine and suddenly from one day it starts giving me this error whenever i try to install app using `react-native run-ios`
don't know what to do tried deleting the caches and node modules and ios/build. but none of them work.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle. Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133567/provide-a-valid-path-to-the-desired-application-bundle-print-entry-cfbundle). Also there are [a lot of results](https://www.google.com/search?q=provide+a+valid+path+to+the+desired+application+bundle+site:stackoverflow.com) already for this question, did you try any?

Comment: Thanks it solved the issue.